# .htaccess wrongly redirects to non-existent site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I have two domains. One of them contains a latin character, and is thus an IDN url. What I want is to redirect both the regular domain to the IDN domain, and to remove the `www` prefix from both domain names.

My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^regularurl\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.regularurl\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xn--idnurl-ujb\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xn--idnurl-ujb.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is - it redirects correctly to `xn--idnurl-ujb.com`, but in any case (no matter if what url I redirect from - with or without www) appends `www` to the end, so that it becomes like this: `xn--idnurl-ujb.com/www`. This is clearly not what I intended, as that url is non-existent and redirects to the 404 site. I can't understand why this happens - I've tried many different code variations, too. I've successfully done some `.htaccess` redirects in the past, but they weren't IDN domain names - does that have anything to do with it? What am I doing wrong?

Also, if there is anything I could do to make the code easier or more dynamic, please let me know.

Comment: There is nothing about those rules that would cause it to add www to the end. If this is all that's in your htaccess file, try clearing your browser cache and also try in another browser.

Comment: @PanamaJack Thanks for confirming there's no errors in the code. But please - try for yourself. The real url is [ostlandstakst.no](http://ostlandstakst.no), which should be redirected to østlandstakst.no (IDN: xn--stlandstakst-ujb.no). See what I mean? Maybe this has something to do with the server, host or something else? I have no idea.

Comment: I think it's something with your host. Is your document root `www`? you might want to check your vhost setup.

Comment: YES, that must be it, thanks! The document root is `www`, but the `.htaccess` file is laying outside, at the same level as the `www` folder. I don't know if I could control the document root location, since this is an external host. Any idea what I could do?

Comment: If you are able to access www and your files are in www. move your .htaccess inside www. That's where it should be, in the document root where your files are.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. It started working instantly when moving the file. For the record, I wasn't the one placing those files, just got this project, and since they were there from before, I just assumed everything was in the right place.